# How to fire a command at HH:29:55 and HH:59:55 in a windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, period, periodicity

In a windows batch file (x.bat), how can I fire a command once every 30 minutes, when the second component of the time is greater than 55?

What I have now is:

```
:loop
    program.exe
    PING localhost -n 1800 >NUL
goto loop
```

The problem is that the timing is not precise enough, ie. sec>55 at min%30==29.

Comment: Well, how about showing your code? This is way too broad.

Comment: The question has been updated.

Comment: So what is the reason you are not using the scheduler?

Comment: I am not very proficient in coding windows batch commands. How do I use the scheduler?

Comment: ok...I think I got it. Don't you want to post a proper answer? ;)

Comment: Well, if I post an answer for task scheduler, then my answer will be off topic. :)

Comment: Wait a minute... I don't think the task scheduler provides that level of control, ie. every 30 minutes. The options are merely: Daily, Weekly, Monthly....

Comment: No, you will set it up daily, and under advanced settings set rpeat task every 30 minutes, the give a start time of the next hour:29:55

Comment: All set. I hope it will be working.

Comment: ok, well let me know, it is only in a few minutes. I will create a scripting related answer for you anyway, even though scheduler is perfect for this task.

Comment: The Task Scheduler just fired the command perfectly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, Task Scheduler is more than capable for this task. It can be run daily, every 30 minutes starting at `next hour:59:55`

That said, there are ways to script these things. This is not the most robust solution, but it works.

```
@echo off
:start
for /f %%i in ('powershell Get-Date -Format mm:ss') do (
    if "%%i"=="29:55" program.exe
    if "%%i"=="59:55" program.exe
timeout 1 /nobreak>nul
)
goto start
```

Comment: Apparently a problem with the Task Scheduler is that if the PC restarts, I have to launch the task again. Is there a workaround? Currently, I am placing my batch scripts in shell:startup.

Comment: well, there is the option of the script I posted if you want to retain the exact 29:55 and 59:55 rule.